# Problem when copying array of different types using Arrays.copyOf

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a method that pretty much takes anything as a parameter, and returns a concatenated string representation of the value with some delimiter.

```
public static String getConcatenated(char delim, Object ...names) {
String[] stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(names, names.length, String[].class); //Exception here
return getConcatenated(delim, stringArray);
}
```

And the actual method

```
public static String getConcatenated(char delim, String ... names) {
if(names == null || names.length == 0)
    return "";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    String n = names[i];
    if(n != null) {
        sb.append(n.trim());
        sb.append(delim);
    }
}

//Remove the last delim
return sb.substring(0, sb.length()-1).toString();
}
```

And I have the following JUnit test:

```
final String two = RedpillLinproUtils.getConcatenated(' ', "Shervin", "Asgari");
Assert.assertEquals("Result", "Shervin Asgari", two); //OK

final String three = RedpillLinproUtils.getConcatenated(';', "Shervin", "Asgari");
Assert.assertEquals("Result", "Shervin;Asgari", three); //OK

final String four = RedpillLinproUtils.getConcatenated(';', "Shervin", null, "Asgari", null);
Assert.assertEquals("Result", "Shervin;Asgari", four); //OK

final String five = RedpillLinproUtils.getConcatenated('/', 1, 2, null, 3, 4);
Assert.assertEquals("Result", "1/2/3/4", five); //FAIL
```

However, the test fails on the last part with the exception:

`java.lang.ArrayStoreException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2763)`

Can someone spot the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The cause

You can't put an `Integer` in a `String[]`. That's why you get `ArrayStoreException`. `Arrays.copyOf` does no conversion.

From [the API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28U%5B%5D,%20int,%20java.lang.Class%29):

> `T[] copyOf(U[] original, int newLength,  Class< ? extends T[]> newType)`
>
> **Throws**: `ArrayStoreException` - if an element copied from `original` is not of a runtime type that can be stored in an array of class `newType`

The [`ArrayStoreException` API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html) has an example:

> Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects. For example, the following code generates an `ArrayStoreException`:
>
> ```
>     Object x[] = new String[3];
>     x[0] = new Integer(0);
> ```

#### See also

- [JLS 10.10 Array Store Exception](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.10)

---

#### The fix

That said, you actually don't need a `String...` and `Arrays.copyOf` to a `String[]`. Your `getConcatenated` can just take `Object...` and it'd work just fine.

```
public static String getConcatenated(char delim, Object... objs) {
    if(objs == null || objs.length == 0)
        return "";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Object o : objs) {
        if(o != null) {
            if (sb.length() > 0) sb.append(delim);
            sb.append(o.toString().trim());
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Now you can do the following:

```
    System.out.println(getConcatenated(';', "Shervin", null, "Asgari", null));
    // prints "Shervin;Asgari"

    System.out.println(getConcatenated('/', 1, 2, null, 3, 4));
    // prints "1/2/3/4"

    System.out.println(getConcatenated(':', "  ", null, "boo", "boo"));
    // prints "boo:boo"
```

Note that this follows the intended specification in the original code, i.e. `trim()` and skips `null`.

Answer (score 6):

Since you can't store, say `Integers`, in a `String[]` array, there is no way you can just copy an array of objects into an array of Strings. You have to somehow go through `.toString()` on each object.

This solution would for instance work:

```
public static String concat(char delim, Object... objs) {
    if (objs == null || objs.length == 0) return "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Object o : objs)
        sb.append(delim).append(o);
    return sb.substring(1);
}
```

As a side note on varargs; I doubt you need to check if `objs == null`. The compiler will turn a call of the from `concat(",", "a", "b", "c")` into `concat(",", new Object[] {"a", "b", "c")`, thus I can't see how `objs` could ever equal `null`. -->

Comment: +1, but will go out of bounds on the substring if the Object list is empty, add a `if (objs == null || objs.length == 0) return "";` on top.

Comment: But if delim is a String, then this call would fail: 
`concat("/", "1","2");` Doesn't the delim have to be char if you want to pass it like that?

Comment: I missed that, I took the more general option of having it as a string. Changed to char.

Comment: @Shervin, why would it fail in case the signature is `(String s, String... strs)`?

Comment: @aioobe: Its strange, when I first tested it, the compiler complained, but when I test it again, it doesn't complain...

Answer (score 1):

You can only copy `String`s into a `String[]`.

`System#arraycopy` and `Arrays#copyOf` do not do any type conversions, you have to turn the objects into Strings one by one yourself, for example by calling `String#valueOf` (the null-safe version of `Object#toString`).

Why not change the method to accept `Object...` instead of `String...` and call `String.valueOf(obj)` on each of them.