# Java: invoke Object vararg method with an int array

Tags: java, arrays, variadic-functions

have a method with the following signature:

```
public static String concatAndSeperate(Object seperator, Object... obj)
```

The purpose of the method is to concat the objects in obj with a seperator in between the entries of obj.

Now I have an int array that I cannot modify due to heavy side effects.

```
int[] numbers = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

I want to use those numbers for an SQL IN statement:

```
SELECT * FROM quux WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
```

So I try to concat it with my nice little method:

```
concatAndSeperate(", ", numbers);
```

This doesn't work, of course, since numbers is an integer array and not an Integer array. So I try to make an Integer array out of it:

```
concatAndSeperate(", ", Arrays.asList(numbers).toArray(new Integer[numbers.length]);
```

This causes a nice error I do not understand:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.toArray(Unknown Source)
at mystuff.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:415)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem when copying array of different types using Arrays.copyOf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882350/problem-when-copying-array-of-different-types-using-arrays-copyof)

Comment: Why don't you simply send the string "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7" to your method and keep life simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use commons-lang to do the leg-work for converting the primitive into a wrapper array for you (see [ArrayUtils.toObject(int[])](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toObject%28int%5B%5D%29):

```
concatAndSeparate(", ", ArrayUtils.toObject(numbers));
```

However, is there a reason why you're not just storing numbers as

```
Integer numbers = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
```

Comment: Thanks for the common-lang input. We already have this library included in our project, so this saves a couple of lines. Changing the int array to an Integer array is not that simple, because this array is used in dozens or even hundreds of places in my project. I get 27 build errors when changing it.
I think this whole wrapper class stuff is a major design flaw of the Java language. The same with generics, which are implemented by adding wrappers in the compiled code all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

The [ArrayStoreException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html), tell you that yuo try to put invalid type to an array.

The problem that [Arrays.asList(T... a)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html), create a list from its arguments.

You problem is that generics do not work on primitive types.

When you pass array of int, the generic vararray will recognize the type as int array, and will create single item on output `List<int[]>`.

To "fix" that, just change the primitive array to object

`Integer[] numbers = new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};`

Comment: Ah, sorry, I obfuscated my code and forgot to modify everything. Here's the code how it should look like:

    Arrays.asList(numbers).toArray(new Integer[numbers.length]

Comment: And Language.ALL in my original code is just a reference to an int array in a Class called Language.

Comment: Ah, Arrays.asList(numbers) makes a List collection object containing one entry: the int array. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

According to API Arrays.asList(T... a)  returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.  That is Arrays.asList(numbers) creates an internal array of int[] elements with length = 1 and copies int[] as one element there

```
List<int[]> list =  Arrays.asList(numbers);
```

then list.toArray() creates Integer[] array and then tries to copy int[] array as one Object to Integer array element 0 which causes ArrayStoreException

BTW you could get the required result this way

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM quux WHERE id IN " + Arrays.toString(numbers).replace('[', '(').replace(']', ')');
```

Comment: Thank you, that's also a solution, but it doesn't seem very solid. If toString() is modified in certain ways, it won't work anymore. So I rather convert my int[] to Integer[] using a loop. But thanks anyway!

Comment: It will never change because Arrays.toString API describes exactly how it formats int[]: The string representation consists of a list of the array's elements, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (a comma followed by a space).

Comment: Well, the API describes how it is implemented at the moment. But that doesn't mean that it will never change. Of course, that is really unlikely to happen, but it still could. An API description is not an eternal contract.